# List elements getting overwritten in for loop R?

Tags: r, list, csv, for-loop

I have a bunch of csv files that I'm trying to read into R all at once, with each data frame from a csv becoming an element of a list. The loops largely work, but they keep overriding the list elements. So, for example, if I loop over the first 2 files, both data frames in list[[1]] and list[[2]] will contain the data frame for the second file.

```
#function to open one group of files named with "cores"
open_csv_core<- function(year, orgtype){
  file<- paste(year, "/coreco.core", year, orgtype, ".csv", sep = "")
  df <- read.csv(file)
  names(df) <- tolower(names(df))
  df <- df[df$ntee1 %in% c("C","D"),]
  df<- df[!(df$nteecc %in% c("D20","D40", "D50", "D60", "D61")),]
  return(df)
}

#function to open one group of files named with "nccs"
open_csv_nccs<- function(year, orgtype){
  file2<- paste(year, "/nccs.core", year, orgtype, ".csv", sep="")
  df2 <- read.csv(file2)
  names(df2) <- tolower(names(df2))
  df2 <- df2[df2$ntee1 %in% c("C","D"),]
  df2<- df2[!(df2$nteecc %in% c("D20","D40", "D50", "D60", "D61")),]
  return(df2)
}
#############################################################################
yrpc<- list()
yrpf<- list()
yrco<- list()
fname<- vector()
file_yrs<- as.character(c(1989:2019))
for(i in 1:length(file_yrs)){
  
  fname<- list.files(path = file_yrs[i], pattern = NULL)

#accessing files in a folder and assigning to the proper function to open them based on how the file is named  
for(j in 1:length(fname)){
    
    if(grepl("pc.csv", fname[j])==T) { 
      
      if(grepl("nccs", fname[j])==T){
        a <- open_csv_nccs(file_yrs[j], "pc") 
        yrpc[[paste0(file_yrs[i], "pc")]] <- a
        
      } else {
        b<- open_csv_core(file_yrs[j], "pc")
        yrpc[[paste0(file_yrs[i], "pc")]] <- b
      }
      
    } else if (grepl("pf.csv", fname[j])==T){
      
      if(grepl("nccs", fname[j])==T){
        c <- open_csv_nccs(file_yrs[j], "pf")
        yrpf[[paste0(file_yrs[i], "pf")]] <- c
        
      } else {
        d<- open_csv_core(file_yrs[j], "pf")
        yrpf[[paste0(file_yrs[i], "pf")]] <- d
      }
      
    } else {
      
      if(grepl("nccs", fname[j])==T){
        e<- open_csv_nccs(file_yrs[j], "co")
        yrco[[paste0(file_yrs[i], "co")]] <- e
        
      } else {
        f<- open_csv_core(file_yrs[j], "co")
        yrco[[paste0(file_yrs[i], "co")]] <- f
      }
    }
    
    
  }

}
```

Comment: These are quite a lot duplicated code. Can you explain in human language what is the point of the code? Are all files to be read in the same way? Or which differences are there?

Comment: I also didn't got the  "overriding" part. What you mean with that?

Comment: Or what exactly is the logics of the function names? How many csv files is that?

Comment: There are about 100 files named with similar (but annoyingly slightly different) naming conventions. Generally, for each year from 1989-2019 there are 2-3 files each year of three types - pf, pc, and co. Some files are named using "nccs" and some are named using "core." For example, a file could be named: 2019nccspf.csv or 2019coreco.csv, etc. Given there is no consistent structure to which combinations are possible, I wrote the loops to check first for the type in the name (pc, pf, co) (so I can use that type in the function), and then whether the name has "nccs" to get the right file path.

Comment: Regarding the "overriding" - let's say I have a pf file for 2018 and 2019. I want the 2018 pf to be a data frame in list element [[1]] and the 2019 pf to be in the same list as element [[2]]. Instead, what I am getting is the 2019 pf in both [[1]] and [[2]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, both of your csv reading functions do exactly the same,
except that the paths are different.

If you find a way to list your files with abstract paths instead of relative
paths (just the file names), you wouldn't need to reconstruct the paths like
you do. This is possible by `full.names = TRUE` in `list.files()`.

The second point is, it seems there is never from same year and same type
a "nccs.core" file in addition to a "coreco.core" file. So they are mutually
exclusive. So then, there is no logics necessary to distinguish those cases, which simplifies our code.

The third point is, you just want to separate the data frames by filetype ("pc", "pf",  "co") and years.

Instead of creating 3 lists for each type, I would create one **res**-ults list, which contains for each type an inner list.

I would solve this like this:

```
years <- c(1989:2019) 

path_to_type <- function(path) gsub(".*(pc|pf|co)\\.csv", "\\1", path)

res <- list("pc" = list(),
            "pf" = list(),
            "co" = list())

lapply(years, function(year) {
  files <- list.files(path = year, pattern = "\\.csv", full.names = TRUE)
  dfs <- lapply(files, function(path) {
    print(path) # just to signal that the path is getting processed
    df <- read.csv(path)
    file_type <- path_to_type(path)
    names(df) <- tolower(names(df))
    df <- df[df$ntee1 %in% c("C", "D"), ]
    df <- df[!(df$nteecc %in% c("D20", "D40", "D50", "D60", "D61")), ]
    res[[file_type]][[year]] <- df
  })
})
```

Now you can call from result's list by file_type and year
e.g.:

```
res[["co"]][[1995]]
res[["pf"]][[2018]]
```

And so on.

Actually, the results of the `lapply()` calls in this case are
not interesting. Just the content of `res` ... (result list).

Comment: This worked excellently; thank you so much. The only modification I made was that "years<- c(1989:2019)" needed to be wrapped in as.character() for the list.files to work, but otherwise seamless.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in your `for(j in 1:length(fname)){...` you are creating one of 4 variable `a`, `b`, `c` or `d`. And you're reusing these variable names, so they are getting overwritten.

The "correct" way to do this is to use `lapply` in place of the `for` loop. Pass the list of files, and the required function (i.e. `open_csv_core`, etc) to `lapply`, and the return value that you get back is a list of the results.